# MS SQL version of MySQL Repeat function

Tags: mysql, sql-server, repeat, nested-sets

I was looking into creating a nested set for a hierarchical structure to create a categories table for a web site on an MSSQL 2008 express database.  I have been following this guide which was written for MySQL: http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/ and was wondering what the MSSQL version of the REPEAT function in the following statement is:

```
SELECT CONCAT( REPEAT( ' ', (COUNT(parent.name) - 1) ), node.name) AS name
FROM nested_category AS node,
    nested_category AS parent
WHERE node.lft BETWEEN parent.lft AND parent.rgt
GROUP BY node.name
ORDER BY node.lft;
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show some sample data and desired results, so that those not fluent in MySQL syntax can understand what you're asking for?

Comment: @AaronBertrand It looks like it's just a string repetetion command.  In this example it's basically indenting the sub-categories to be below the parent categories, like `REPLICATE`

Comment: @JNK Right, I get the part about `REPLICATE` but I assume the op also wants to simulate the `CONCAT` function which does not have an equivalent in SQL Server (well, there is one in SQL Server 2012 but it is not a group concat). Understanding the input and desired output will help with that part too. Otherwise, why bother with the nested-sets tag and all the query details?

Comment: Ok, never mind, guess it was just superfluous information. Wonder how `CONCAT` is working out.

Comment: @AaronBertrand it does seem like concat would be the sticky part though...

Comment: @JNK I'm guessing we'll see another question before long.

Comment: @AaronBertrand @JNK I must be missing something... I would think that the [`concat` could just be replaced with `+`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) in SQL Server.

Comment: Not if it's meant to concatenation across rows. Which may or may not be what Olly is after. Which is why I immediately asked for sample data and desired results - so we don't have to guess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you're looking for [`REPLICATE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174383.aspx):

```
SELECT REPLICATE(' ', COUNT(parent.name) - 1) + node.name AS name
FROM nested_category AS node,
nested_category AS parent
WHERE node.lft BETWEEN parent.lft AND parent.rgt
GROUP BY node.name
ORDER BY node.lft;
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for TSQL's [`REPLICATE()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174383.aspx) function which takes the same parameters in the same order for the same effect.

Edit: Maybe I should clarify, there are some differences in border cases like the count being negative, but for "normal" use, it behaves like the same function.